# Difference of proto messages with the relative positions of its attributes

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

what is the difference if the attribute in a protobuf message is first or second member?

The Request proto message i have, has 2 fields. i am asked to interchange the position of the attributes

```
message SomeRequest {
  SomeMessage1 message1 = 1;
  SomeMessage2 message2 = 2;
}
```

Changed to  :

```
message SomeRequest {
  SomeMessage2 message2 = 1;
  SomeMessage1 message1 = 2;
}
```

What could be the possible reasons of such a advice? message2 is expected to be more predominately searched?
Also can i have few more scenarios to understand it better?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, whoever asked for this change - maybe ask them for their reasons?

There *are* scenarios where lower field numbers are cheaper (space-wise) and so should be preferred, but fields 1 and 2 are identical in terms of space, so this this isn't a concern here.

If this was for byte compatibility with a pre-existing similar type, it might be a reasonable request.

Comment: byte compatibility ? I didn't understand,, can u plz elaborate little

Comment: No this is not for byte compatibility. This message is newly created.

Comment: @discoverAnkit : Compatibility of mesage with previous message format he meant.

Comment: @Nilotpal then there really aren't any "obvious" reasons; you're going to have to ask them "why?"